# Отправка checkbox на почту через php

Tags: php, html

Первое скрипт, второе код формы, помогите пожалуйста розобраться как отправить выбранные элементы на почту

Сайт с формой: http://asvpage.mcdir.ru/1/index.html#four

```js
<?php 
//отключаем вывод ошибок
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
session_start();
include('config.php');
$check = '';
if (!empty($_POST["check"]) && is_array($_POST["check"]))
{
    $check = implode(" ", $_POST["check"]);
}
$name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$phone = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$mail = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']));
$hidden = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden']));

if(empty($name) || empty($phone)){
echo '<h1 style="color:red;">Пожалуйста заполните все поля</h1>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'">';
}
else{


$get = http_build_query($order);

unset($_SESSION['check']);
unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['phone']);
unset($_SESSION['mail']);
unset($_SESSION['hidden']);
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
$_SESSION['mail'] = $mail;
$_SESSION['hidden'] = $hidden;
$subject = 'Заказ товара - "'.$product.'"'; // заголовок письма
$addressat = $email; // Ваш Электронный адрес
$sender="{$product} <noreply@{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}>"; // Адрес отправителя
$header="charset='UTF-8'\r\nFrom: {$sender}\r\n";

$message = "Услуга: {$hidden}\ncheck: {$check}\nИмя: {$name}\nКонтактный телефон: {$phone}\nПочта: {$mail}\nТовар: {$product}\n\nСайт продажи: {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}\nВремя покупки: ".date("m.d.Y H:i:s")."\n\nИнформация о покупателе:\nIP покупателя: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\nУстановленный язык: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}\nБраузер и ОС: {$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}\nРеферер: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}\n\nUTM-метки:\nutm_source= {$_SESSION['utms']['utm_source']}\nutm_medium= {$_SESSION['utms']['utm_medium']}\n&utm_term= {$_SESSION['utms']['utm_term']}\nutm_content= {$_SESSION['utms']['utm_content']}\nutm_campaign={$_SESSION['utms']['utm_campaign']}";
$success_url = 'form-ok.php';

$verify = mail($addressat,$subject,$message,$header);
if ($verify == 'true'){
 echo("<script>document.location.href = '{$success_url}';</script>");
    //header('Location: '.);
    echo '<h1 style="color:green;">Поздравляем! Ваш заказ принят!</h1>';
    exit;
}
else 
    {
    echo '<h1 style="color:red;">Произошла ошибка!</h1>';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
    <div class="quiz-section" id="four">
      <div class="div-block-82">
        <h3 class="h2-video">Подберите бассейн для себя ответив на 4 вопроса</h3>
        <p>Ответьте на 4 простых вопроса и оставьте свой контакт. Мы перезвоним в течение часа. По итогу консультации вы узнаете какой бассейн подойдёт именно вам, сколько он будет стоить и срок его реализации</p>
      </div>




      <div id="form_wrapper" class="form-block-2 w-form">
 

    <form class="form-2" id="quiz-form" role="form" action="zakaz.php" method="post" onsubmit="if(this.name.value==''){alert('Введите Ваше имя');return false}if(this.phone.value==''){alert('Введите Ваш номер телефона');return false}return true;">

          <div data-w-id="0e601157-9d80-257f-65fb-31de764444e1" class="step-1 padding-step">
            <div class="text-block-25">Вопрос 1 из 4</div>
            <div class="text-block-19">Выберите назначение бессейна</div>
            <div class="div-block-86">
              <div data-w-id="dfafa499-306e-8c25-887f-837f68355fbc" class="radio-wrapper">
                <img src="images/check.png" width="46.5" data-w-id="37e2a2d0-40fa-bf6f-c2e7-fef45233e3c8" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">


                    <input class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Бетонный" data-name="naznachenie">
                    <label for="Бетонный" class="field-label w-form-label"><span class="text-span"> </span><span class="text-span-2"><b>Бетонный</b></span>
                      <p class="descr-bas">
                        <b>+</b> Любая форма<br>
                        <b>+</b> Любой вид отделки<br>
                        <b>+</b> Доступная стоимость<br>
                      </p>
                    </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="ac5e2546-cd25-6151-56fa-6a8702ce9a88" class="radio-wrapper"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Композитный" data-name="naznachenie">
                  <label for="Композитный" class="field-label w-form-label"><span class="text-span _2"> </span><span class="text-span-2"><b>Композитный</b></span>
                      <p class="descr-bas">
                        <b>+</b> Повышенная прочность<br>
                        <b>+</b> Повышенный срок службы <br>
                        <b>+</b> Гигиеничность и простота обслуживания
                      </p></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="88cc7212-28fe-f91b-c569-bf56101143bb" class="radio-wrapper"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Общественный" data-name="naznachenie">
                  <label for="Общественный" class="field-label w-form-label"><span class="text-span _3"> </span><span class="text-span-2"><b>Общественный</b></span>
                      <p class="descr-bas"><b>+</b> Размеры: большой<br>
                        <b>+</b> Любой вид отделки<br>
                        <b>+</b> Повышенный срок службы 
                      </p></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="f2337dbb-0cff-8b45-d819-b21a4dace31c" class="radio-wrapper"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="radio" name="sbornii" value="Сборный" data-name="naznachenie">
                  <label for="Сборный" class="field-label w-form-label"><span class="text-span _4"> </span><span class="text-span-2"><b>Сборный</b></span>
                      <p class="descr-bas"><b>+</b> Быстрота монтажа<br>
                        <b>+</b> Доступная стоимость <br>
                      </p></label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#quiz-form" data-w-id="729f2b31-1cca-bbc6-34f5-557fa5b7f278" class="button-big w-inline-block">
              <div>Следующий вопрос</div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div data-w-id="a855da6b-b506-8dbb-0a7f-1c378427852b" style="display:none;opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0)" class="step-2 padding-step">
            <div class="text-block-25">Вопрос 2 из 4</div>
            <div class="text-block-19">Размер помещения под бассейн</div>
            <div class="div-block-87">

            <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field text-field-2 w-input" type="text" name="dlina" placeholder="Длина" value>
            <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field text-field-2 w-input" type="text" name="siri" placeholder="Ширина" value>
            <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field text-field-2 w-input" type="text" name="glub" placeholder="Глубина" value>

            </div>
            <a href="#quiz-form" data-w-id="2293fe24-6ab7-2506-a7b5-6027be35c481" class="button-big w-inline-block">
              <div>Следующий вопрос</div>
            </a><a href="#form_wrapper" data-w-id="d0035852-73ff-0ff4-eaf6-ea90c0daebc8" class="back-link">Назад</a></div>
          <div data-w-id="d8fae634-42f6-fead-b18e-184c20ffe9f8" style="display:none;-webkit-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0" class="step-3 padding-step">
            <div class="text-block-25">Вопрос 3 из 4</div>
            <div class="text-block-19">Размещение</div>
            <div class="div-block-86-copy-copy">
              <div data-w-id="54ab9229-a124-0d61-f649-977493f11aec" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Внутри помещения" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Внутри помещения" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Внутри помещения <span class="span-text-mini">Круглогодичное использование</span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="2ed4b8de-dd2d-0042-63c5-4b7fb5fc4140" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Уличный открытый" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Уличный открытый" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Уличный открытый <span><span><span class="span-text-mini">сезонное использование, больше грязи, больше потребление химикатов</span></span></span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="47e82d84-041c-5adf-8edc-0b1285dcc172" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Уличный закрытый" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Уличный закрытый" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Уличный закрытый <span class="span-text-mini">сезонное использование</span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="0cb9db52-dade-fd55-c715-f50fceb230e6" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Ламели" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Ламели" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Ламели<span class="span-text-mini">Автоматическое покрытие, защитит от падения ребенка в бассейн, сократит испарение и защитит от загрязнения</span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="b3b52119-f062-51f1-8b49-0e77cefe0bfa" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Пузырьковое покрытие" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Пузырьковое покрытие" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Пузырьковое покрытие<span class="span-text-mini">Недорого, сокращает испарение и защищает от загрязнения воды</span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-w-id="c3c8a467-1032-b54d-3869-7654d673f915" class="radio-wrapper _2"><img src="images/check.png" width="36" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(0.5) scaleY(0.5) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);opacity:0;display:none" class="check-on _3">
                <div class="radio-button-field w-radio">

                  <input id="Razmer" class="form-control field radio-button w-radio-input" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Павильон" data-name="razmeshenie">
                  <label for="Павильон" class="field-label-2 w-form-label">Павильон<span class="span-text-mini">Ручное раздвижное покрытие, сокращение испарения и защита от загрязнения</span></label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#quiz-form" data-w-id="89368522-800d-c1b1-3c94-09c81346748f" class="button-big w-inline-block">
              <div>Следующий вопрос</div>
            </a><a href="#form_wrapper" data-w-id="8bd8b8d6-a615-d1a2-81db-8f3e6da055b7" class="back-link">Назад</a></div>
          <div data-w-id="ef5e6ab6-3f9a-5dc4-64cb-0823e79a95c1" style="display:none;opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-moz-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);-ms-transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0);transform:translateX(150PX) translateY(0) translateZ(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skewX(0) skewY(0)" class="step-4 padding-step">
            <div class="discout-plate">
              <div class="div-block-112">
                <div class="h2-video-copy">Спасибо за ответы!</div>
                <div>Оставьте свой контакт и получите:</div>
                <div class="text-block-32">Предварительную стоимость бассейна, на основе ваших ответов</div>
                <div class="text-block-32">Консультацию, по итогам которой вы поймёте какой бассейн вам подойдёт</div>
                <div class="text-block-32">Ответы на все ваши вопросы</div>
              </div>
              <div class="div-block-87-copy">
                <div>Куда отправить рассчёт?</div>
                <div class="div-block-92">
                  <div class="radio-button-field-2 w-radio">

                    <input class="form-control field radio-button-2 w-radio-input" id="sms"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">
                    <label for="sms" data-w-id="231a8dfb-6cc5-ac99-da76-9ae7d10f1872" style="background-color:rgb(245,245,245)" class="mess-checkbox w-form-label">E-mail</label>

                  </div>
                  <div class="radio-button-field-2 w-radio">

                    <input class="form-control field radio-button-2 w-radio-input" id="wts" type="checkbox" name="check[]">
                    <label for="telegram-2" data-w-id="95f22230-47f7-628e-ffb9-53ed732de6b2" class="mess-checkbox _2 w-form-label">Whatsapp</label>

                  </div>
                </div>


              <input class="form-control field text-field _2 w-input" id="phone-3" type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Введите имя" value>
              <input class="form-control field text-field _2 w-input" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" title="+7(XXX)XXX-XX-XX" id="phone2" required="required" value>
              <input class="form-control field text-field-2 _100 w-input" type="mail"  name="mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail" title="+7(XXX)XXX-XX-XX" value>
                <button class="form-control btn button-m button-big w-inline-block button-big _2 w-button" type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>

                <div class="div-block-93">
                  <div class="text-block-24">Нажимая на кнопку, вы принимаете Положение и Согласие на обработку персональных данных.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="success-message w-form-done">
          <div><strong class="bold-text">Заявка отправлена. Мы уже приступили к расчету стоимости.</strong><br>Мы пришлем стоимость на указанный номер телефона</div>
          <div class="text-block-26">Пока посмотрите наши кейсы</div><a href="#projects" class="button-big w-button">Смотреть кейсы</a></div>
        <div class="w-form-fail">
          <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В коде name="check[]" а нужно что-то вроде name="check[sms]" — тогда cможете анализировать его в post.

Comment: в html вместо name="check[]" заменить на name="check[вариант]", а в скрипте php как это прописать ?

Comment: У вас довольно запутанный код, поэтому подскажу только основу. Неотмеченные чекбоксы в post не передаются. Поэтому вы должны проверять каждый чекбокс в виде if (isset($_POST['check']['sms'])) ..отмечен..  else .. не отмечен... Либо второй вариант кинуть в рядом с чекбоксами input с type=hidden и тем же именем (value=0), что и чекбокс. Тогда поле точно попадет в post-данные.